# Removing earlier duplicates from a list and keeping order

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I want to define a function that takes a list as an argument and removes all duplicates from the list except the last one.

For example:
`remove_duplicates([3,4,4,3,6,3])` should be `[4,6,3]`. The [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order) answers do not solve this one.

The function is removing each element if it exists later in the list.
This is my code:

```
def remove(y):
    for x in y:
        if y.count(x) > 1:
            y.remove(x)
            
    return y
```

and for this list:
`[1,2,1,2,1,2,3]` I am getting this output:
`[2,1,2,3]`. The real output should be `[1,2,3]`.
Where am I going wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Use list(set(a)). This should work, but wonk, but output will be in ascending order.

Comment: @Abhay no, that's not what OP wants. Converting to `set` destroys order. Also please don't answer questions in the comments.

Comment: @Abhay this gives output in order. Thank you though for trying :)

Comment: Getting `[4,6,3]` from `remove_duplicates([3,4,4,3,6,3])` is ***not*** preserving the order of the values in the list being passed as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/480214/4518341) does actually answer the question, but there's an extra step: reverse the input then reverse the output. You could use `reversed` to do this, with an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def remove_earlier_duplicates(sequence):
    d = OrderedDict.fromkeys(reversed(sequence))
    return reversed(d)
```

The output is a reversed iterator object for greater flexibility, but you can easily convert it to a list.

```
>>> list(remove_earlier_duplicates([3,4,4,3,6,3]))
[4, 6, 3]
>>> list(remove_earlier_duplicates([1,2,1,2,1,2,3]))
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

BTW, your `remove` function doesn't work because you're [changing the size of the list as you're iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6260089/4518341), meaning certain items get skipped.

Comment: Welcome! BTW I rejected your edit cause the output is intentionally a reversed iterator object for greater flexibility, like I said. For example you can use it on a bytes object and convert it back to a bytes object on the way out, without an intermediate list: `bytes(remove_earlier_duplicates(b'344363'))` -> `b'463'`

Comment: Okay, cool! I suggested the edit because the question wanted output in a list form. This is just as good though!

Answer (score 1):

I found this way to do after a bit of research. @wjandrea provided me with the fromkeys method idea and helped me out a lot.

```
def retain_order(arr): 
    return list(dict.fromkeys(arr[::-1]))[::-1]
```

Comment: Nice, much simpler! However, [`dict` only preserves order in Python 3.7+ and CPython 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39980323/4518341).